# How to hide object in a cube hole?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to hide an object in a hole, after searching for a solution, I followed this example & successfully create a hole:

https://stemkoski.github.io/AR-Examples/hole-box.html

But when I placed an object inside, it's overlap the hole, instead of being covered behind the faces (image 3)

Image 2 is what I want to achieve but haven't found a way so far.

[image]

I tried with clipping & masking (postprocessing) as well without success.

It would be great if someone could give me a clue.

I found [this](https://twitter.com/jerome_etienne/status/836754117964017664), it's exactly what I'm looking for, but the source was removed.

Comment: If it's in Github, you can always go down memory lane and look at old commits. Your Twitter link is from Feb 2017, and I found [this list of commits](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/commits/master?after=024318c67121bd57045186b83b42f10c6560a34a+1470) from March 2017 that are labelled 'hole in the wall tuning'. I'm sure what you're looking for is in there!

Comment: You're a life-saver! Thanks a bunch, mate!